# Need help debugging a Javascript code and/or getting it to work

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Been pulling my hair out since the past 4 hours. I have two Javascript file, both works completely fine by itself. One is use as a login verification, the other takes my registration page and writes the form to an XML file.

When I took some code from my login JS and place it in my registration JS, my registration JS doesn't even function properly. I'm thinking my issue is probably the placement of my codes.

If I post the complete codes here, the post would be like 10ft long, so here's all my files:
http://www.mediafire.com/?wt9bchq35pdqxgf

By the way, this is not a real world application, it's just something I'm doing.

Here's my original Javascript file for the registration page:

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var FILENAME = 'C:\\Users\\Wilson Wong\\Desktop\\Copy of Take Home Exam - Copy\\PersonXML2.xml';

function SaveXML(UserData) 
{ 


var file = fso.CreateTextFile(FILENAME, true);


file.WriteLine('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n');
file.WriteLine('<PersonInfo>\n');

for (countr = 0; countr < UserData.length; countr++) 
{
    file.Write('    <Person ');
    file.Write('Usrname="' + UserData[countr][0] + '" ');
    file.Write('Pswd="' + UserData[countr][1] + '" ');
    file.Write('PersonID="' + UserData[countr][2] + '" ');
    file.Write('FirstName="' + UserData[countr][3] + '" ');
    file.Write('LastName="' + UserData[countr][4] + '" ');
    file.Write('Gender="' + UserData[countr][5] + '" ');
    file.Write('DOB="' + UserData[countr][6] + '" ');
    file.Write('Title="' + UserData[countr][7] + '" ');
    file.WriteLine('></Person>\n');
} // end for countr
//file.WriteLine('></Person>\n');

var usrn = document.getElementById("Usrn").value;
var pswd = document.getElementById("Pswd").value;
var pid = document.getElementById("PersonID").value;
var fname = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
var gender = document.getElementById("Gender").value;
var dob = document.getElementById("DOB").value;
var title = document.getElementById("Title").value;

file.Write('    <Person ');
file.Write('Usrname="' + usrn + '" ');
file.Write('Pswd="' + pswd + '" ');
file.Write('PersonID="' + pid + '" ');
file.Write('FirstName="' + fname + '" ');
file.Write('LastName="' + lname + '" ');
file.Write('Gender="' + gender + '" ');
file.Write('DOB="' + dob + '" ');
file.Write('Title="' + title + '" ');
file.WriteLine('></Person>\n');    

file.WriteLine('</PersonInfo>\n');
file.Close();
} // end SaveXML function --------------------

function LoadXML(xmlFile) 
{
xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
return xmlDoc.documentElement;
} //end function LoadXML()

function initialize_array() 
{
var person = new Array();
var noFile = true;
var xmlObj;
if (fso.FileExists(FILENAME)) 
{
    xmlObj = LoadXML(FILENAME);
    noFile = false;
} // if
else 
{
    xmlObj = LoadXML("PersonXML.xml");
    //alert("local" + xmlObj);
} // end if

var usrCount = 0;
while (usrCount < xmlObj.childNodes.length) 
{
    var tmpUsrs = new Array(xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Usrname"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Pswd"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("PersonID"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("FirstName"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("LastName"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Gender"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("DOB"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Title"));
    person.push(tmpUsrs);
    usrCount++;
}   //end while
if (noFile == false)
    fso.DeleteFile(FILENAME);
SaveXML(person);
}   // end function initialize_array()
```

This code here will write to my XML file after I hit the submit button. And this is how the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PersonInfo>

<Person Usrname="Bob111" Pswd="Smith111" PersonID="111" FirstName="Bob" LastName="Smith" Gender="M" DOB="01/01/1960" Title="Hello1" ></Person>

<Person Usrname="Joe222" Pswd="Johnson222" PersonID="222" FirstName="Joe" LastName="Johnson" Gender="M" DOB="12/01/1980" Title="Hello2" ></Person>

<Person Usrname="Tracey333" Pswd="Wilson333" PersonID="333" FirstName="Tracey" LastName="Wilson" Gender="F" DOB="12/01/1985" Title="Hello3" ></Person>

<Person Usrname="Connie444" Pswd="Yuiy444" PersonID="444" FirstName="Connie" LastName="Yuiy" Gender="F" DOB="12/01/1985" Title="Hello4" ></Person>

<Person Usrname="Brian555" Pswd="Dame555" PersonID="555" FirstName="Brian" LastName="Dame" Gender="M" DOB="12/01/1985" Title="Hello5" ></Person>

<Person Usrname="Scott666" Pswd="Bikes666" PersonID="666" FirstName="Scott" LastName="Bikes" Gender="MF" DOB="12/01/1985" Title="Hello6" ></Person>

<Person Usrname="sadsa" Pswd="s" PersonID="s" FirstName="s" LastName="s" Gender="s" DOB="s" Title="s" ></Person>
```

If I modify my code to what is shown below, the XML file won't even create. Nor will the authentication run properly. As in the the box won't turn red and no alert message pops up. But the codes I add in does work on my other JS file for my log in page.

Here's the edited registration JS:

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var FILENAME = 'C:\\Users\\Wilson Wong\\Desktop\\Copy of Take Home Exam - Copy\\PersonXML2.xml';        
function SaveXML(UserData) 
    {   
var file = fso.CreateTextFile(FILENAME, true);

file.WriteLine('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n');
file.WriteLine('<PersonInfo>\n');

for (countr = 0; countr < UserData.length; countr++) 
{
    file.Write('    <Person ');
    file.Write('Usrname="' + UserData[countr][0] + '" ');
    file.Write('Pswd="' + UserData[countr][1] + '" ');
    file.Write('PersonID="' + UserData[countr][2] + '" ');
    file.Write('FirstName="' + UserData[countr][3] + '" ');
    file.Write('LastName="' + UserData[countr][4] + '" ');
    file.Write('Gender="' + UserData[countr][5] + '" ');
    file.Write('DOB="' + UserData[countr][6] + '" ');
    file.Write('Title="' + UserData[countr][7] + '" ');
    file.WriteLine('></Person>\n');
} // end for countr

var usrn = document.getElementById("Usrn").value;
var pswd = document.getElementById("Pswd").value;
var pid = document.getElementById("PersonID").value;
var fname = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
var gender = document.getElementById("Gender").value;
var dob = document.getElementById("DOB").value;
var title = document.getElementById("Title").value;

var errmsg = "empty field";
var errmsg2 = "You have register successfully";
var msg = "This user name is already in use";          //this is what I added
var errCount = 0;

errCount += LogInVal(usrn);
errCount += LogInVal(pswd);
errCount += LogInVal(pid);
errCount += LogInVal(fname);
errCount += LogInVal(lname);      //this is what I added
errCount += LogInVal(gender);
errCount += LogInVal(dob);
errCount += LogInVal(title);

if (errCount != 0)                      //the if/else statements are what I added
{
    file.WriteLine('</PersonInfo>\n');      //checks to see if textbox is empty, if yes, alert
    file.Close();
    alert(errmsg);
    return false;
}

else if(authentication(usrn) == true)
{
    file.WriteLine('</PersonInfo>\n');        //checks to see if user name entered is already in use
    file.Close();
    alert(msg);
    return false;    
}

else
{
    file.Write('    <Person ');
    file.Write('Usrname="' + usrn + '" ');
    file.Write('Pswd="' + pswd + '" ');
    file.Write('PersonID="' + pid + '" ');
    file.Write('FirstName="' + fname + '" ');
    file.Write('LastName="' + lname + '" ');       //this block of code here was there originally
    file.Write('Gender="' + gender + '" ');
    file.Write('DOB="' + dob + '" ');              //previous two condition is false, registration successful, writes to XML.
    file.Write('Title="' + title + '" ');
    file.WriteLine('></Person>\n');    

    file.WriteLine('</PersonInfo>\n');
    file.Close();

    alert(errmsg2);
    return true;
}
     } // end SaveXML function --------------------

  function authentication(usrname1)            //function was added
 {
 for (var x = 0; x < arrPerson.length; x++)
 {
    if (arrPerson[x][0] == usrn)
        {
            return true;
        }     
 }
 return false;    
 }

   function LogInVal(objtxt)                //function was added
  {
       if(objtxt.value.length == 0)
{
    objtxt.style.background = "red";
    return 1;
}

else
{
    objtxt.style.background = "white";
    return 0;
}
  }

function LoadXML(xmlFile) 
{
xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
return xmlDoc.documentElement;
} //end function LoadXML()

function initialize_array() 
{
var person = new Array();
var noFile = true;
var xmlObj;
if (fso.FileExists(FILENAME)) 
{
    xmlObj = LoadXML(FILENAME);
    noFile = false;
} // if
else 
{
    xmlObj = LoadXML("PersonXML.xml");
    //alert("local" + xmlObj);
} // end if

var usrCount = 0;
while (usrCount < xmlObj.childNodes.length) 
{
    var tmpUsrs = new Array(xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Usrname"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Pswd"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("PersonID"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("FirstName"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("LastName"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Gender"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("DOB"),
                            xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Title"));
    person.push(tmpUsrs);
    usrCount++;
}   //end while
if (noFile == false)
    fso.DeleteFile(FILENAME);
SaveXML(person);
}   // end function initialize_array()
```

Here's the login page JS, which contains the code(it works fine in this file) that was added to the registration JS:

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

//DEFINE LOAD METHOD
function LoadXML(xmlFile)
{
 xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
 xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;
}

//declare & initialize array
var arrPerson = new Array();

//initialize array w/ xml
function initialize_array()
{
LoadXML("PersonXML.xml");
var x = 0;
while (x < xmlObj.childNodes.length)
{
var tmpArr = new Array(xmlObj.childNodes(x).getAttribute("Usrname"), 
                       xmlObj.childNodes(x).getAttribute("Pswd"), 
                       xmlObj.childNodes(x).getAttribute("FirstName"), 
                       xmlObj.childNodes(x).getAttribute("LastName"), 
                       xmlObj.childNodes(x).getAttribute("DOB"),
                       xmlObj.childNodes(x).getAttribute("Gender"),  
                       xmlObj.childNodes(x).getAttribute("Title"));
arrPerson.push(tmpArr);
x++;   
}
}

//Validation
function LogInVal(objtxt)
{
if(objtxt.value.length == 0)
{
    objtxt.style.background = "red";
    return 1;
}

else
{
    objtxt.style.background = "white";
    return 0;
}
}

//main validation
function MainVal(objForm)
{
var errmsg = "empty field";
var errmsg2 = "Incorrect Username and Password";
var msg = "You have logged in successfully";
var errCount = 0;

var usrn = document.getElementById("usrname1").value;
var pswd = document.getElementById("pswd1").value;

errCount += LogInVal(objForm.usrname);
errCount/*1*/ += LogInVal(objForm.pswd);

initialize_array();    

if (errCount != 0)
{
    alert(errmsg);
    return false;
}
else if(authentication(usrn, pswd) == true)
{

    alert(msg);
    return true;
    setCookie('invalidUsr',' ttttt');
}
else
{
    alert(errmsg2);
    return false;
}
}

function authentication(usrname1, pswd1)
{
for (var x = 0; x < arrPerson.length; x++)
{
    if (arrPerson[x][0] == usrname1 && pswd1 == arrPerson[x][1])
        {
            return true;
        }     
}
return false;    
}

function setCookie(Cookiename,CookieValue)
{
alert('executing setCookie');
document.cookie = Cookiename + '=' + CookieValue;
}
```

Here's my registration HTML page:

```
<html>
<!--onSubmit="SaveXML(person);"-->
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_LABs.css" />
</head>


<body>
<script type="text/javaScript"  src="writeXML.js"> </script>

<div class="form">
<form id="Registration" name="reg" action="" method="get" onSubmit="return initialize_array()">

Username:<input type="text" name="Usrn"  id="Usrn" maxlength="10"/> <br/>
Password:<input type="password" name="Pswd" id="Pswd" maxlength="20"/> <br/>

<hr>

PersonID:<input type="text" name="PersonID" id="PersonID"/> <br>

<hr>

First Name:<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName"/> <br>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName"/>

<hr>

DOB:<input type="text" name="DOB" id="DOB"/> <br>

<hr>

Gender:<input type="text" name="Gender" id="Gender"/> <br>

<hr>

Title:<input type="text" name="Title" id="Title"/> <br>

<hr>

<!--Secret Question:<br>
<select name="secret?">
</select> <br>

Answer:<input type="text" name="answer" /> <br> <br>-->

<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope I'm not being too confusing.

Comment: Look for errors you get in tools->error console in firefox and see what kind of errors you are getting

Comment: Forgot to mention that this only works in IE. IE doesn't seem to be displaying any errors. Forgot to mention, Syntax seems fine. Just that the code doesn't seem to run the way I want it to.

Comment: It would help if you could identify 1) What the expected behavior was (eliminate need for <Person>?), and 2) Where/how it is failing?

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @brettz9 What that line of code is doing is just creating a XML file on the fly. <person> is the root element. Before I add those additional code, it's running properly and creates my XML without issue. Once I add them, my XML file is not even being created. 

@Arun using IE 8.

Comment: Looks like <PersonInfo/> is the root, not <person/>...

Comment: Forgot to mention what the if/else statement is doing. First it checks to see if the textbox is empty, if it is, the box will become red and a alert message would pop up saying so. If it's not empty, it will check to see if the user name entered exist in the XML file. If it does, it will prompt the user that the user name is already in use. The else is for when both condition is false, the registration is successful, and it will write the strings in the textbox to the XML file.

Comment: @brettz9 yeah you're write, got a bit confused when I was looking at the files.  


For some odd reason, I can't seem to get the code to run properly after I put in the authentication.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/aCkQx/1/ . This is how to make a test case to communicate the problem to other people without requiring them to learn your whole app. This code is working fine (at least to what I'd expect), so I'd suggest either explaining how this differs from expected behavior or building another simplified test case showing where exactly things go unexpected for you.

Comment: Was given that once before, no idea how to use it. After adding the if/else statement and the variables, my XML file would not create and the the text box won't go red even if I leave it blank. You should be able to get a better understanding if you had download my files on mediafire. If you feel unsafe with downloading the files, I can post all my codes up if you like. But not sure if it would be fun to read though.

Comment: @MNX1024 if you can't create an exact example in a few lines that indicates the problem, how can we help you find what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm suppose to produce. I guess I'll just edit my post and post the codes.

Comment: Alright, just finish editing the page. Do hope it helps.

Comment: It would really help if you trim it down further. The point is to make a test case which reduces the problems which saves US time (and possibly yourself as well). For example, reduce it down to just one attribute and one textbox, and see if the problem is still there. If it is, then you can help us focus on the problem, rather than needing to do work you could do. (This is not a homework completion site, but identifying problems site--though it is looking better.)

Comment: There's no syntax error according to Dreamweaver. It's really hard to trim stuff down because it's calling functions from all over the place and the function is called from onsubmit on the HTML page. Problem is, if you look at the original registration JS, the code runs completely fine and creates the XML file. Once I add those authentication code to it, the file won't even create and nothing runs. Once again, no syntax error, that's where I'm confused because the code I place in also works on another file by itself.

Answer (score 0):

What I see in the code is this:

```
create XML file, start with <personInfo>
if error, skip </personInfo>
now add something else.
```

so you're not closing the XML element. Of course it won't create the file. It won't write invalid XML, and that's "expected" behavior.

Comment: Mind elaborating it and giving me an example with my code? I'm actually new to web programming, so there's a lot I don't know. Just learned some basic Javascript recently.

Comment: Actually I kept rereading and kept rereading and I saw where it does close the element. But I still think it's an issue with malformed XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can also debug your jvascript code  to enable javascript debugging. go to : tools > intenet options > advanced > browsing and uncheck (disable script debugging). in **Internet Explorer Browser** . then you can attach debugger by writing **debugger;** @ any location in javascript function egs: 
function SaveXML(UserData)
 {
    debugger;
    var file = fso.CreateTextFile(FILENAME, true);  file.WriteLine('\n'); 
    file.WriteLine('\n');
.........................
}

Comment: After putting debugger, what am I suppose to expect? Do I just run my HTML page afterwards?

Comment: yes, just refresh your web page on which that script should be running. but i suppose you have created html page just out of notepad or some editor. actually you will need to have some ide like VisualStudio2008 you can download a free version and it will start debugging for you whenever you refresh your page. and have debugger; writtern in the JS function

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver, it's not showing any syntax error. It's just that the code won't run after I edit it.